# Error when loading a .shp file after joining attributes from a .csv to a .dbf file

Tags: r, csv

I am having problems opening the .shp file in R after I have joined attributes from a csv file to the dbf file. I have a lot of experience coding in R, but limited experience with GIS in R. I have experience in ArcGIS, but do not have access to the program anymore. I know how to create bubbleplots and other maps in R using the csv file and plotting points, but I would like to be able to add the attributes to the .dbf, then use the shapefile to fill in the county areas with the brewer palette. I can open the shape file fine before joining the attributes to the .dbf file (the files were obtained from the us census bureau webpage).

Here is my code below:

```
library(gpclib)
library(maptools)
library(RColorBrewer)
library(classInt)
library(TeachingDemos)


gci<-read.csv("C:/Users/Smackbug/marketingmapexample.csv", header=TRUE) #Has Geo_ID
#read in dbf file to append data
gci2<-gci
gci2<-na.omit(gci2) #remove any empty data points

#read in dbf file to add attributes
akdbf<-read.dbf(file.choose())#downloaded from the us census bureau

#merge to join attributes
joined<-merge(akdbf,gci2, by=c("GEO_ID"))
#Save original and new dbf
write.dbf(akdbf, "C:/Users/Smackbug/Desktop/shapefiles/gz_2010_02_060_00_500koriginal.dbf")
write.dbf(joined, "C:/Users/Smackbug/Desktop/shapefiles/gz_2010_02_060_00_500k.dbf")
```

and I get the error from this part of the code

```
**alaska<-readShapePoly(file.choose(),proj4string=CRS("+proj=longlat") )
Error in `row.names<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, value = value) : 
  invalid 'row.names' length**
```

and the rest of the code

```
#the rest of the code should look something like this

colors<-brewer.pal(5,"Reds")
brks<-classIntervals(alaska$medianIncome, n=5, style="fixed", fixedBreaks=c(0,25,50,100,250))
plot(brks, pal=colors)
brks<-brks$brks
plot(alaska, col=colors[findInterval(alaska$medianIncome, brks, all.inside=TRUE)], axes=F)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are breaking the sp (shapefile) object in multiple ways. You cannot not add data to the dbf independently of the operating on the shapefile. Everything is indexed in one of the binary files (shx) comprising the shapefile. You are also breaking the internal relationship of the sp object by using merge.

The most efficient way is to use rgdal to read the shapefile, join the dbf, and finally write out (or overwrite) a new shapefile.

```
require(rgdal)
require(sp)
require(foreign)

# Read data
shp <- readORG(getwd(), "ShpName")
tbl <- read.dbf("infile.dbf")

# Merge data using match
shp@data = data.frame(shp@data, tbl[match(shp@data[,"GEO_ID"], tbl[,"GEO_ID"]),])

# Write new shapefile with added attributes, THe additional flags will overwrite if 
#   the name is the same as the original 
writeOGR(shp, getwd(), "NewShp", driver="ESRI Shapefile", check_exists=TRUE, overwrite_layer=TRUE)
```

If you need a more formal merge function you can use this.

```
##########################################################################
# PROGRAM: merge.sp.df
#
# USE: JOINS A dataframe OBJECT TO A sp CLASS SpatialDataFrame OBJECT
#        KEEPING INTEGRITY OF DATA
# 
# REQUIRES: sp CLASS SpatialDataFrame OBJECT 
#    PACKAGES: sp
#
# ARGUMENTS: 
#   x       sp SpatialDataFrame OBJECT
#   y       dataframe OBJECT TO MERGE
#   xcol    MERGE COLUMN NAME IN sp OBJECT
#   ycol    MERGE COLUMN NAME IN dataframe OBJECT
#
# EXAMPLE:
#   # Not Run (dat.sp is sp object and dat is a data.frame to merge
#   dat.sp <- merge.sp.df(dat.sp, dat, "dat.sp-ID", "dat-ID")
#
# VALUE:
#   A NEW SpatialDataFrame OBJECT WITH MERGED DATA
##########################################################################
merge.sp.df <- function(x, y, xcol, ycol) {
  x@data$sort <- 1:nrow(as(x@data, "data.frame"))  
    xdf <- as( x@data, "data.frame")
     xdf <- merge(xdf, y, by.x=xcol, by.y=ycol) 
       xdf <- xdf[order(xdf$sort), ]
         row.names(xdf) <- xdf$sort
      xdf <- xdf[,- which(names(xdf) == "sort")]     
    x@data <- xdf  
   return(x)
}
```

Comment: I thought this might be the case, but I have seen a few examples from where others have written similar code, though I can tell that they have probably removed some of their coding steps. I'll have to try something like above and see if it works. If not, I know another way I can do it.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a working result (thanks Jeffery for your help) using some of Jeffery's code above:

```
library(sp)
library(rgdal)
library(foreign)

setwd("C:/Users/rhonda/Documents/R scripts/shapefiles")
gc<-read.csv("gcmarketingmapexample.csv", header=TRUE) 
#read in dbf file to append data
akdbf<-read.dbf("gz_2010_02_060_00_500k.dbf")
#merge to join attributes
joined<-merge(akdbf,gc, by=c("GEO_ID")`enter code here`

#save new dbf 
write.dbf(joined, "akdbf")

#Shape File and DBF file 
frame<-readOGR(getwd(),"gz_2010_02_060_00_500k")
akdbf2<-read.dbf("akdbf.dbf")

frame@data=akdbf2[match(frame@data[,"GEO_ID"], akdbf2[,"GEO_ID"]),]
writeOGR(frame,getwd() , "akdbf",driver="ESRI Shapefile", check_exists=TRUE, overwrite_layer=TRUE)
#use new shapefiles to create maps
```